# Как отключить странный режим выделения в pycharm?

Tags: pycharm

Вот как он выглядит. Не знаю как отключить. Помогите пожалуйста
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не пользуюсь PyCharm, но мне кажется или alt или ср. кнопка мыши залипла

Comment: @RottenRat Проверил.. К сожалению это именно какой - то режим

Comment: @RottenRat При этом он очень не удобный... Клик по строке перемещает не на конец строки, а на место куда был произведен клик...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это *Column Selection Mode*, чтобы его включить/выключить, нажмите <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Insert</kbd>.

Comment: Приведённое сочетание клавиш это способ его выключения?

Comment: @wchistow Да, выключит или включит